# PHP 7.2.23 MongoDB\Driver\Manager Array Cluster return empty

Tags: php, mongodb

I installed the mongodb driver for PHP 7.2.23 includes the extension "extension = mongodb.so" in php.ini, phpinfo () returns that it is active, but when trying to connect to the database does not return the cluster data.
Any one can help me?

## Amazon Linux 2

Comands
yum install php-pear
yum install php-devel
yum install mongo-c-driver
pecl install mongodb

PHP code:

```
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://user:pass@mongo1.com.br:28710,mongo2.com.br:28710,mongo3.com.br:28710/admin?replicaSet=rsMpsystems");

var_dump($mongo);
```

returns:

```
object(MongoDB\Driver\Manager)#1 (2) {
  ["uri"]=>
  string(195) "mongodb://mongodb://user:pass@mongo1.com.br:28710,mongo2.com.br:28710,mongo3.com.br:28710/admin?replicaSet=rsMpsystems"
  ["cluster"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

phpinfo()
MongoDB support enabled
MongoDB extension version   1.6.0
MongoDB extension stability stable
libbson bundled version 1.15.1
libmongoc bundled version   1.15.1
libmongoc SSL   enabled
libmongoc SSL library   OpenSSL
libmongoc crypto    enabled
libmongoc crypto library    libcrypto
libmongoc crypto system profile disabled
libmongoc SASL  enabled
libmongoc ICU   disabled
libmongoc compression   enabled
libmongoc compression snappy    disabled
libmongoc compression zlib  enabled

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem!

```
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://user:pass@mongo1.com.br:28710,mongo2.com.br:28710,mongo3.com.br:28710/admin?replicaSet=rsName");
$stats = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(["dbstats"=>1]);
$res = $mongo->executeCommand("db_name",$stats);
var_dump($res->toArray());
```

PHP 7.2.24 Amazon Linux 2 
PECL mongodb 1.6.0 
Done!